# How to prevent jade markdown filter from adding IDs to the headers?

Tags: templates, pug, markdown

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent Jade from adding IDs to the headers when it parses markdown into HTML.

The problem is, that

```
### Hello, world!
```

is being parsed into

```html
<h3 id="hello-world-">Hello, world!</h3>
```

How can I get rid of the id attribute?

Comment: Please add your `JADE` code